# How to keep the screen position from "zt" after switching buffer

Tags: buffers, scrolling

When I use `zt` to scroll the screen relative to the cursor and then switch buffers with, say, `:bn` followed by `:bN`, the screen jumps back to the position before executing `zt`.

Using for example `ctrl-d` to scroll in the buffer doesn't have this side effect.

How can I keep the cursor & screen position when using the `z`-family of commands and toggling between buffers?

Comment: Note that `zz`, `zt` and `zb` do not move the cursor, they just move the window view. On the contrary `<C-d>` is moving the cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**  use autocommands, see the end of this post.

---

Here's the result of the investigation I've made:

Calling `bn` call the [`ex_bnext` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2932359000b2f918d5fade79ea4d124d5943cd07/src/ex_docmd.c#L5517-L5522) which does two things:

- Go to the desired buffer via the `goto_buffer` function
- Execute any command line command passed to the `bnext` command

The [`goto_buffer` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2932359000b2f918d5fade79ea4d124d5943cd07/src/buffer.c#L831) apparently wrap the more generic `do_buffer` function and calls it with special argument related to the action of going to a buffer (see the first argument is the action which is either `DOBUF_SPLIT` or `DOBUF_GOTO`).

The [`do_buffer` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2932359000b2f918d5fade79ea4d124d5943cd07/src/buffer.c#L1143) is pretty long, but you can see the interesting part around the end. This function calls the `set_curbuf` function.

The [`set_curbuf` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2932359000b2f918d5fade79ea4d124d5943cd07/src/buffer.c#L1485) set the current buffer to the desired buffer and calls `enter_buffer`.

The [`enter_buffer` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2932359000b2f918d5fade79ea4d124d5943cd07/src/buffer.c#L1604) set/reset some options for the newly displayed buffer **and** calls `scroll_cursor_halfway`.

Finnaly, the [`scroll_cursor_halfway` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2932359000b2f918d5fade79ea4d124d5943cd07/src/move.c#L2066) changes the topline value, meaning the cursor will be displayed halfway the window.

Sooo, I think it's the designed behavior.

---

What you can do is, when leaving a buffer, save the current window display with `winsaveview` and on entering a buffer, reset the view with autocommands:

```
autocmd! BufWinLeave * let b:winview = winsaveview()
autocmd! BufWinEnter * if exists('b:winview') | call winrestview(b:winview) | unlet b:winview
```